# Запустить подключение по WPS к Wi-Fi из командной строки в Windows 10

Tags: windows, wifi, powershell

Не могу найти решение как стартовать *WPS* клиент в *Windows 10* из командной строки (*command prompt* или *powershell*). На линуксе было все достаточно просто, там можно было использовать `wpa_supplicant` из *hostapd* (`wpa_cli wps_pbc`).

Кто-то сталкивался с этим? Я скачал семпл на плюсах с использованием *WCN* (написано, что он реализует фичи *WPS*), но по факту этой утилитой не могу заставить взять пароль сети по *WPS*, хотя стандартными средствами *Windows* подключиться по *WPS* получается (без пина).

Важно то, что необходимо инициировать подключение посредством *WPS* именно из командной строки (или иначе автоматизировать **без человеческого участия** - кто-то засветил *WPS*, сразу взять пароль и подключиться).

Comment: а почему не по имени ?

Comment: Я заранее не знаю имя сети. Устройство под управлением Windows нужно подключить к Wi-Fi сети, не имея никаких интерфейсов ввода.